# how to List date in order of number of another data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :teacher_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :users, :through =>:feedback
  has_many :feedbacks
end


class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects 
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end

class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :rating, :recommendations, :strengths, :subject_id, :user_id,       :weaknesses
   belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course_id, :email, :gender, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :feedbacks
  has_many :subjects, :through =>:feedback
end
```

There is a join table between course and subjuct
I am a student and freshman in rails,I have some problem in this final project
How to

1. List subjects in order of number of feedbacks.
2. List students with no feedbacks.

I have no idea how to do it. Thanks very much

Comment: `@subjects = Subject.find(:all, :include=>:feedbacks).sort_by { |p| p.feedbacks.size}`

Comment: if u need query for listing students with no feedbacks I will provide u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing solution for two queries you need:

> **List subjects in order of number of feedbacks**

```
@subjects = Subject.find(:all, :include=>:feedbacks).sort_by { |p| p.feedbacks.size}
```

> **List students with no feedbacks**

```
User.find(:all, :include => :feedbacks, :conditions => "feedbacks.id is null")
```

Comment: If I want to list user have no feedback in a specific subject which meaning no just list user with anyone feedback?How to mend the condition?

Comment: just attach this condition with a `.where("condition here")`